# Using jQuery Serialize in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, serialization

what is the usage of [jQuery Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) API in ASP.NET ?
how can we use it ?
Is it possible to convert  serialized object to .NET strong type object?
Or map the serialized object to into .NET equivalent  object?
for example we have two field in a 'member' table.
Name , Age.
so we have these properties in Member Entity ;

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
public string Age { get; set; }
```

And we have these codes in our presentation layer :

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

When I serializing form using this code :

```
$.fn.serializeNoViewState = function()
{
    return this.find("input,textarea,select,hidden")
               .not("[type=hidden][name^=__]")
               .serialize();    
}
```

the Serialized object will be like this :

> ```
> ctl00%24MainContent%24txtName=Pitter&ctl00%24MainContent%24txtAge=20
> ```
>
> so is this string or JSON object? I think its string.
>   and now what are the benefits of this Serialized output for us?
>   I know that we are able to pas this output to server using jQuery AJAX. but how can we use it Server Side?

Comment: Please notify me if my question is not clear or needs more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation explains it the [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method is passed a form DOM element and it converts it into a URL encoded string of key/value pairs that you could pass to the server. But if you want to work with strongly typed objects in ASP.NET you could take a look at [Page Methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). For example suppose that you have defined the following type:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

you could then have a page method:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Process(Person person)
    {
         // TODO: do some processing
         return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    ...
}
```

and to invoke this method using jQuery and JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/Process',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'foo', // you could fetch those values dynamically
        age: 25
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        // msg.d will contain the object returned from the server
        // in our example it's a simple string but you could use any
        // complex type you like (well almost any, it must be JSON serializable)
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. was so useful. you commented '// you could fetch those values dynamically' would you please describe more?

Comment: @shaahin, what I meant was that you could bind those parameters to input fields in your form. For example: `name: $('.name').val()`. In this example I use a class selector as ASP.NET mangles names and ids of input elements.